# Clarification on how throwing and catching custom exceptions in Java

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

So I have this program that is basically recreating SQL in java. I have this "driver" class that sorta controls the whole thing. It calls and instantiates various classes and methods to make it all work. With in this I have this method

```
public void checkCommand(String input) {

for (Command c : commands) {
    if (c.matches(input)) {
        try {
            c.execute();
        } catch (MyException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return;
    }
}
System.out.println("That was not a valid command.");
```

Execute is a method that will get called on every command entered. So every thing goes through this at some point. Within the DefineTableCommand class, execute contains

```
database.addTable(tableName, fieldList);
```

database is a singleton instance of the Object I'm using to to store all the tables. The addTable command calls a few other things and so on. Within these, I have some methods that could go wrong, like the table name already exists or something along those line.

```
public void addTable(String tableName, String fieldList) throws MyException {
    Table table;
    table = new Table(tableName, fieldList);
    if (instance.checkForDuplicates(tableName)) {
       throw new MyException(
            "There was a table with that name already present.");
    } else {
         instance.tableCollection.put(tableName, table);
    }
}
```

Now, What I want to happen, and what I thought would happen, was that the exception would be thrown from addTable, the exception would be passed up the stack to the catch in the checkCommand. This does not seem to be the case and I'm not sure I understand why.

To explain further. The user is given a prompt in which they enter various commands (define table emp having fields (name varchar) for example) if there is an issue with their command, they should see an error message, but the program should keep running. so lets say they enter a table with the same name as a table already present, they should be given an error message and the program continues with no new table. Instead no error message is printed, but the table still isn't added.

Comment: you need to show us a full example, because as it stands this is incomplete at best.

Comment: That is the case unless you catch it somewhere else and do not rethrow it. Please paste the rest of the code.

Comment: try to provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) reproducing your misunderstanding. This can done in just a few lines of code.

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out a way to condense this because I feel my issue comes from the error being called and thrown about four classes in. Meaning, Execute is called from the Driver class, which is a method in the Command Interface, which in the particular example, Execute is in the Define table class, which class addTable from the TableCollection class which calls the constructor of the Table class which also throws custom exceptions.

Comment: "This does not seem to be the case" doesn't give any description of what you're actually seeing, which makes it impossible to try to *explain* what you're seeing.

Comment: Does the method that calls `database.addTable(tableName, fieldList);` catch any exceptions? Or does the method that calls _that_ method?

Comment: Exceptions are exceptions whether they're yours or the system's. Either you're not throwing it, or something is catching it.

Comment: IF you are having a hard time condensing it, what chance do you think we have?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that part of the signature of execute() is:

```
    execute() throws MyException
```

And in its implementation doesn't catch MyException like:

```
    //eg
    void execute() throws MyException
    {
      database.addTable(tableName, fieldList);
     //any code
    }
```

If this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not catching **MyException** before it is thrown by **Command** classes execute() method

Comment: catch an `Exception` **before** it is thrown?